# Can I use render_template() in a Flask view function being called from javascript?

Tags: javascript, python, templates, flask

I have a javascript function in my template that runs periodically to call a view function.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var contact = "{{ contact }}"
setInterval(                               
  function()
  {
     $.getJSON(                            
        $SCRIPT_ROOT + '/show_convo_update',      
        { contact: contact }, {});                               
  },
1000);
</script>
```

I know it calls the view function every 1000 ms because it performs all the logic I need in the view function, but when it gets to the render_template line, nothing happens. I want it to open up the new template, but instead the template with the javascript call stays up. Here's the view function.

```
@app.route('/show_convo_update')
@login_required
def show_convo_update():
    contact = request.args.get('contact')        
    msgs = getconvo(contact)
    return render_template('testjq.html', msgs=msgs) #this line doesn't do what I want
```

Does the javascript function maybe expect something else to be returned? Any ideas?

Comment: As the name implies, `getJSON` expects JSON. Based on the name of your template, however, it looks like you are sending it HTML.

Comment: As @dirn commented, you should response in JSON. Check out flask.request.content_type and flask.jsonify().

Comment: Thanks, that helped. What I ended up doing is using jsonify() to return the URL of the page that I wanted to load, and then loaded that URL from the javascript function. Seems like a decent solution, but if there is a better way, please let me know.